# Create local npm package with local dependencies and install it in another package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have created three different custom modules.

1. getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz
2. getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz
3. setrediscache-1.0.0.tgz

I have created these custom node module using **npm pack** command. The module getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz has dependencies on another two custom modules (getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz, setrediscache-1.0.0.tgz) which are created locally.

The problem that I am facing is that when I try to install getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz in another node project, it throws the error as below:

> npm install getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz npm ERR! addLocal Could not install
>   C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz
>   npm ERR! addLocal Could not install
>   C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\setrediscache-1.0.0.tgz
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz" npm ERR! node v6.3.1 npm ERR! npm 
>   v3.10.3 npm ERR! path
>   C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz'
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
>   ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
>   ERR! enoent npm ERR! Please include the following file with any
>   support request: npm ERR!
>   C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\npm-debug.log

My package.json file for getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz is :

```
{
   "name": "getcorrespondence",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "Get Correspondence Module",
    "author": {
       "name": "XYZ",
       "email": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
       "getrediscache": "file:./getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz",
       "jslinq": "^1.0.15",
       "setrediscache": "file:./setrediscache-1.0.0.tgz",
       "soap": "^0.16.0"
    }
}
```

What changes are required to correctly install the package.

After creating the getcorrespondence package, my tgz file look like:

[image]

Comment: I guess, you have an outdated `npm` and should update it before you try issuing your `npm install` command.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the options like **npm install npm@latest** and **npm cache clean**. But is it still not working.

Comment: Also, can you please try adding a blank `.npmignore` file to your folder after removing existing one?(Seems you already have one with 69 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

NPM's errors are usually frustratingly cryptic. The relevant part in that wall of text is `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Repos\Microservices_APIs\PaymentsAPI\CommonAPI.Specs.Unit\getcorrespondence-1.0.0.tgz\getrediscache-1.0.0.tgz'`, which basically means npm expected the file to exist in that path, but it isn't.

I assume the cause is an incorrect path in your `package.json`.